# Linux apache /etc/hosts setup on a live server

Tags: linux, apache2, host

I have a Linode server operating under a single IP Address. I access various websites via the single IP addresses in the following format: `http://x.x.x.x/mysite1`

**Is it possible to access my individual websites, mysite1 etc, via names set in /etc/hosts?**

In /etc/hosts I tried setting:

```
x.x.x.x   dev.mysite
```

But, attempting to access my website via *http://dev.mysite* results in a **webpage not found** error.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have made the `/etc/hosts` modification on the machine that is trying to access the website, then yes this is possible. Although you will also have to modify your Apache config so it knows which website to display when "dev.mysite" is requested. My Apache knowledge is rudimentary but I believe you want [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) for this.

If you want other people to access the website without modifying their hosts file, you will need to buy a domain. For instance, if you buy xyz.com, you can put your sites under site1.xyz.com, site2.xyz.com and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Your /etc/hosts needs no change . dev.mysite already points to mysite.com which has an entry in /etc/hosts

You need to modify your web server (nginx / Apache)listening in port 80 to accept requests on dev.mysite